# socketio-objc SocketIOPacket Parsing

Tags: objective-c, socket.io

I have the packet data coming in on a recieveEvent delegate.

getting dictionary of packet.dataAsJSON works, and doing an NSLog on that looks like this

```
args = (
{
id = "123";
name = "John Doe";
status = "Yeah";
}
};
= "JoinedChat";
```

First, I'm confused as to why it has '=' and ';' instead of ':' and ','

Second, when I getObjectAtKey:@"args", I don't get another dictionary of 3 objects , I get a dictionary of 1 object...and there's no keys...if I parse it as an Array, and get objectsAtIndex:0, I'm getting 3 objects but not dictionaries, I'm trying to access the data in there, but it isn't working. help please

Answer (score 0):

I use the below code in my app:-

```
NSData *data = [packet.data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

then use "json" variable and reload the table. This is working in my chat application.